# Moving Data from Access (32-bit) to Visual Studio (64-bit) Database

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, ado.net, strongly-typed-dataset

I do not seem to be able to get the TableAdapter.Insert to actually add a row to the database pointed to by the VideoDBDataSet

VideoDBDataset points to VideoDBDataSet.xsd
RecsTableAdapter is the TableAdapter that points to Recs
TableAdapterManager points to RecsTableAdapter

I have tried with both Update and without Update but neither work.

BindingSource points to VideoDBDataset with Recs as the actual Table

'pRecs is a structure containing the fields to add to the Database
'CoverBytes is the Byte Data of a JPG file

```
Private Sub FillNewDatabase()
    Dim CoverBytes() As Byte

    'We do this here because CoverBytes is used in this routine
    ReDim CoverBytes(0)
    Call GetCoverBytes(pRecs.Common.CoverPath, CoverBytes)

    RecsTableAdapter.Insert(pRecs.Common.Title,
                pRecs.Common.Director,
                pRecs.Common.Cast,
                pRecs.Common.Related,
                pRecs.Common.Genre,
                pRecs.Common.Rated,
                pRecs.Common.Release,
                pRecs.Common.Length,
                pRecs.Common.Link,
                pRecs.Common.AKA,
                pRecs.Common.Created,
                pRecs.Common.Synopse,
                pRecs.Common.Comment,
                pRecs.Common.AutoAdded,
                pRecs.Common.Series,
                pRecs.Common.Seasons,
                pRecs.Common.Episodes,
                CoverBytes,
                pRecs.Common.CoverPath,
                pRecs.DVD.DVDInfo,
                pRecs.DVD.DVDBurned,
                pRecs.DVD.DVDVob,
                pRecs.DVD.DVDCollection,
                pRecs.DVD.DVDDisks,
                pRecs.DVD.DVDIndexed,
                pRecs.DVD.DVDFiled,
                pRecs.DVD.DVDPoor,
                pRecs.DVD.DVDErrors,
                pRecs.DVD.DVDMissing,
                pRecs.DVD.DVDReplace,
                pRecs.DVD.DVDNote,
                pRecs.DVD.DVDFiledAs,
                pRecs.DVD.DVDQuality,
                pRecs.DVD.DVDReviewed,
                pRecs.DVD.DVDSubEnglish,
                pRecs.DVD.DVDSubForeign,
                pRecs.DVD.DVDAudioEnglish,
                pRecs.DVD.DVDAudioForeign,
                pRecs.PlayOn.POInfo,
                pRecs.PlayOn.PODownloaded,
                pRecs.PlayOn.POCommercials,
                pRecs.PlayOn.POMissing,
                pRecs.PlayOn.POReplace,
                pRecs.PlayOn.POLow,
                pRecs.PlayOn.PODan,
                pRecs.PlayOn.POChecked,
                pRecs.PlayOn.POTrimmed,
                pRecs.PlayOn.POPartial,
                pRecs.PlayOn.POLocConfirmed,
                pRecs.PlayOn.POLocation,
                pRecs.PlayOn.POSource,
                pRecs.PlayOn.POAlt,
                pRecs.PlayOn.POResolution,
                pRecs.PlayOn.POReviewed,
                pRecs.PlayOn.PONoteText,
                pRecs.PlayOn.PONoteColor,
                pRecs.PlayOn.POSubEnglish,
                pRecs.PlayOn.POSubForeign,
                pRecs.PlayOn.POAudioEnglish,
                pRecs.PlayOn.POAudioForeign,
                pRecs.Purchase.PurchaseInfo,
                pRecs.Purchase.PurchaseVarified,
                pRecs.Purchase.PurchasePartOfCollection,
                pRecs.Purchase.PurchaseCollectionName,
                pRecs.Purchase.PurchaseDVDs,
                pRecs.Purchase.PurchaseDrawer,
                pRecs.Purchase.PurchaseErrors,
                pRecs.Purchase.PurchaseMissing,
                pRecs.Purchase.PurchaseNoteText,
                pRecs.Word.WordInfo,
                pRecs.Word.WordSpecialNote,
                pRecs.Word.WordSpecialColor,
                pRecs.HardDrive.HDInfo,
                pRecs.HardDrive.HDReplace,
                pRecs.HardDrive.HDMissing,
                pRecs.HardDrive.HDErrors,
                pRecs.HardDrive.HDTextFound,
                pRecs.HardDrive.HDReviewed,
                pRecs.HardDrive.HDResolution,
                pRecs.HardDrive.HDQuality,
                pRecs.HardDrive.HDLabel,
                pRecs.HardDrive.HDFSize,
                pRecs.HardDrive.HDFPath,
                pRecs.HardDrive.HDFName,
                pRecs.HardDrive.HDSubEnglish,
                pRecs.HardDrive.HDSubForeign,
                pRecs.HardDrive.HDAudioEnglish,
                pRecs.HardDrive.HDAudioForeign)
    Validate()
    BindingSource.EndEdit()
    RecsTableAdapter.Update(VideoDBDataSet.Recs)
    TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(VideoDBDataSet)
    VideoDBDataSet.AcceptChanges()
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense at all. You call `Insert`, which is intended to insert a record into the database, but then you validate and end the editing session, then you try to save changes twice more.  Validate first, then end the editing session, then save ONCE.

Comment: Most likely it's working as is but you just aren't checking properly. That may sound odd but it's actually very common because people don't know how local data files work. I don't have a typed `DataSet` handy to test but I think that that `Insert` method should be returning a value. What is that value? That should tell us whether the data is being saved or not. If it is, then we'll address why you can't see it.

Comment: By the way, this question has got nothing at all to do with VBA. The tag description explicitly states that it should not be used for VB.NET questions. Don't add a tag without reading the description and don't add irrelevant tags.